# Determining matching units to evaluate program

Tags: matching

I introduced some treatment to a school (let’s say PS142) and I want to know if my treatment improved students’ math scores compared to the control group. PS142 has 10% minority students and 15 % low income students.

NYC department of education lists 30 peer schools that closely match PS142 on specific characteristics (in terms of % minority and % low income). 
I don’t want to compare PS142 to all 30 peer schools.  I want to just choose 5 or 6 schools from the list of 30 schools.  How do I do this?  What would be the best method?

Comment: Why is it difficult to obtain scores from these schools?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just compare it to the mean of the other schools (using a t-test)? You could first look for and omit any outliers from the control group perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for your response DaGu. 
Yes I thought about making comparison based on the mean of other schools.  The reason I want to just choose 5 or 6 schools from the list is to reduce workload/save time.  I want to look up stats for just a few schools vs. 30 schools ( I have a lot of analyses to run!). 
nj